# Using Rouché prove that $a_0\geq a_1 \geq ... \geq a_n > 0$ the polynomial $P(z)=a_n z^n + ... + a_1 z + a_0$ has no roots $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis

As asked in the title I am trying to prove this using Rouché's theorem. But I am having a hard time trying to find a second polynomial $f(z)$ such that

$$|P(z)-f(z)| < |f(z)|$$

on the unit circle. Could somebody help me out? I would specifically like to see a proof using Rouche's theorem.

Comment: Do you specifically insist on trying it with Rouché's theorem?

Comment: Yes I would like to specifically do it with Rouché's theorem (if possible). I believe that was the goal of the exercise. On a sidenote why is it that the absolute signs drop in the fourth line in the alternate proof?

Comment: Do you mean why $(a_{n+1-k} - a_{n-k})$ and not $\lvert a_{n+1-k} - a_{n-k}\rvert$? These are equal by the monotonicity assumption on the coefficients. If you ask about the whole inequality between the third and fourth line, that's $\lvert X - \sum Y_k\rvert \geqslant \lvert X\rvert - \sum \lvert Y_k\rvert$, but since $X \geqslant 0$, we can omit the absolute value on $X$ (and, as mentioned before, on one of the factors making up the $Y_k$).